# Cron daemon is running and system log daemon is running but cron won't run

Tags: linux, cron

I have a cron that is supposed to run every minute however it will not run. I have checked if the daemon is running and it confirms it is. I have checked for logs but there was no log file created so I so checked rsyslogd and made sure crond will log events, however the log doesn't even get created.

My cron is the following:

```
*/1 * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/xdotool mousemove 500 500
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why cron won't run?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crons don't run the way you want them to because each of them is scheduled as a separate process. Thus the `DISPLAY` variable set in the first job is not shared with the second cron job.

I think you want to combine both of them into one command.

So use `&&` to combine them togather

```
* * * * *  export DISPLAY=:0.0 && /usr/bin/xdotool mousemove 500 500
```

As @RDub has already pointed, `*/1` is redundant.

Comment: Ampersands did the trick. Never had to setup two commands before. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to create a script that contains the env var setting and the xdotool command, then call the script as one line from the crontab.

Also, I think a step of /1 is redundant; This should execute every minute:

`* * * * * command`

Comment: would it look like this * * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 | xdotool mousemove 500 500